# Extract a txz file inside a zipfile in Python

Tags: python, python-zipfile, tarfile

I have a zipfile which has the .txz file. Something like this:

```
 file1.zip
         |
          -- file2.txz
         |
          -- abc.txt
```

I have used `ZipFile` to extract the contents of file1.zip as below:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(mainFile) as zf:
     for files in zf.namelist():
         zf.extract(files, dst)
```

But with this file2.txz is empty having 0 bytes although abc.txt is extracted properly.
How do I properly extract this txz file?

Comment: Can you share ZIP file?

Comment: Does it matter? The file is confidential.

Comment: Most likely ZIP file is corrupted.

Comment: But I'm able to extract manually using winzip